# Pulling a 'counts' list from the first function into the second to update a table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Trying to pull a 'counts' list from the first function into the second to update a table.

I'm using Python, SQLAlchemy, sqlite. I feel like the problem is in my python. Is it the list, tuple? How do I do this?

```
def countCurrentOccupancy():
    p = session.query(Puppy.shelter_id, func.count(Puppy.shelter_id))
    grouped_count = p.group_by (Puppy.shelter_id).all()
    return grouped_count


def updateCurrentOccupancy():
    l = countCurrentOccupancy()
    list_c = list(l)
    s = session.query(Shelter.shelter_id, Shelter.current_occupancy)
    print 'updateCurrentOccupancy:'
    print '----------------------'
    for row_s in s:
        row_s = list_c #Trying to pull matching data from countCurrentOccupancy(), will update to an integer that I choose but that is not helpful.
        print row_s
    session.commit(row_s)
    showShelter()
```

Results:

```
TypeError: commit() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Does `session.commit()` function take argument?

Comment: It will if I replace list_c with an integer. I've gone wrong somewhere but I don't know where. In my mind I need list_c to iterate through the list so it drops the correct number into the correct row. 
I added this        
    ls = countCurrentOccupancy()
     list_c = list(ls)
     print type(list_c)
     print list_c         and it prints this : 
(1, 18)
(2, 29)
(3, 15)
(4, 17)
(5, 21)
so I know it is a list, probably a list of lists?

Comment: Well, what's `row_s` looks like?

Comment: row_s looks like this:
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(3, 2)
(4, 2)
(5, 2)
the 2 is an arbitrary int I put in there to just test the whole thing. I need to replace 2 with the actual value of the count from countCurrentOccupancy()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can transform list into dict {shelter_id: count} and get `count` by `shelter_id`

```
def updateCurrentOccupancy():
    counts_list = countCurrentOccupancy()
    counts_dict = dict(counts_list)

    shelters = session.query(Shelter)
    for shelter in shelters:
        shelter.current_occupancy = counts_dict.get(shelter.id)
        session.add(shelter)

    session.commit()
```

Comment: victory! Thanks rmn and Kevin Guan! It was converting to a dict that allowed me to iterate through the values and it worked exactly as needed.
It worked with this:
counts_dict.get(shelter.shelter_id)